# Integration of Google Ads in a Blazor UI

Tags: ads, blazor, google-ads-api, blazor-server-side

is it possible to integrate Google Ads (AdWords, Adsense, Remarketing) into a BlazorUI page for user tracking, e.g. e-commerce webshop based on Blazor?

Does anyone has a working git demo, how to do that?

Cheers,
Volker

Comment: I found a way to manipulate META tags on the fly:

https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/yet-another-way-to-changing-the-page-title-in-blazor-and-more-43k

Can this technique be used to inject some gtag.js, too?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the answer...

Blazor extensions for Analytics: Google Analytics, GTAG, ...
AspNetCore Version: 3.0.0

https://github.com/isc30/blazor-analytics